# What are negative and positive cycle in graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am not able to understand difference between positive and negative cycle in a weighted graph. The thing that is used bellman ford and SPFA.

What is it?

What are the properties?

If you can please include diagrams/examples of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The graph has weights on its edges.
- The weight of a cycle is the sum of the weights of the edges that make the cycle.
- A cycle is called positive if it has positive weight. A cycle is called negative if it has negative weight.

Think of the graph as a network of roads. Each edge represents one road. You are commuting through this network by car. A positive weight on an edge means you have to pay a toll to drive through that road. A negative weight on an edge means you are given a refund when you drive through that road.

Usually you expect driving through the network will cost you money, because of all the positive weights. When trying to drive from point A to point B, you will try to find a path of minimal cost.

If there is a negative cycle in the graph, then that means a car driving around this cycle will actually gain money instead of paying it.

If I ask you "please find a path with minimal cost from point A to point B" in a graph that has a negative cycle, you might tell me "Well, first go from point A to that cycle. Then, drive around the cycle forever and ever. When you're tired and wealthy, go to point B."

In other words, there are paths with arbitrarily high negative weight. So asking for a path of minimal weight in a graph that has a negative cycle is meaningless, because driving around the negative cycle again and again will always reduce your cost further.

Comment: I have tried to find out why we need to detect the negative cycle. Here is the best explanation so far, IMHO.